# Does a static method in a non-static class make it a static class c#

Tags: c#, .net, static-methods, c#-8.0, static-classes

Possibly a stupid question but I need to ask it anyway for my own context.  I have a non-static class that has a static method and a non-static method.  What happens to the class, is it now a static class and a non-static class, meaning there is a static version of the class with just the static method in memory and when you instantiate the class there will be an instance with all the non-static methods? I may be confusing myself. C# .net framework.
Non-static class with static and non-static method.

```
public class Class1
{
    public static string Class1Method()
    {
        return "static";
    }

    public void Class1Method2()
    {
        //Not Static
    }
}
```

Second class that would be using it.

```
public class Class2
{
    public void Class2Method()
    {
        Class1.Class1Method();
        new Class1().Class1Method2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Class1` is considered *non-static*.

However, if you were to run say ReSharper over `Class1` as it appears above, it may suggest to you to consider making it `static` because `Class1` has **no** *instance members*. i.e. `static class Class1` as well as `public static void Class1Method2`.

Otherwise, as it stands now, there is no point to making `Class1Method2` an instance method because there are no instance members to act upon.